# Azure Service Fabric - trying to update key-value parameters of an application using Powershell

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am trying to update the Key-Value parameters of one of my Service Fabric applications.  **Right now the application version is 2.0.20**.  This is the script my former dev gave to me to update the key-value parameters:

```
New-ServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationName fabric:/Cantanilla.Jef -ApplicationTypeName Cantanilla.Application.JefType -ApplicationTypeVersion 2.0.20 -ApplicationParameter @{key:value pairs}
```

I can't get this script to work. The issue is that if I run this with version 2.0.20, I get the error `Application already exists`.  If I run it with version 2.0.21, I get the error `Application type and version not found`.

How can I accomplish this?  The dev said this script definitely worked for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get it to work with `2.0.21` because you first have to Copy the new version `2.0.21` to the Image store with the command [`Copy-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/copy-servicefabricapplicationpackage?view=azureservicefabricps) and then register as a valid package version with [`Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/register-servicefabricapplicationtype?view=azureservicefabricps)

Also, the command [`New-ServiceFabricApplication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/new-servicefabricapplication?view=azureservicefabricps) that you tried, will create a new application, instead of updating the old one.

To update the old one, you have to use the command [`Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/start-servicefabricapplicationupgrade?view=azureservicefabricps).

The following command should work:

```
Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade -ApplicationName fabric:/Cantanilla.Jef -ApplicationTypeVersion 2.0.20 -Monitored -FailureAction Rollback -ApplicationParameter @{key:value pairs}
```

Keep in mind that you have to provide all the parameters specified when you deployed the application, some might not be possible to change.

Comment: Hi Diego,   Yes I do have to provide ALL the parameters which is ok. Can I get a little more guidance on `Copy-ServiceFabricServiceApplicationPackage`?  I am not sure what I am copying.  I don't have a new version of the application - I just want to update the key-value parameters of the existing.  Or, upgrading to new version is ok too, but I don't have anything to copy?  My developer said he was able to accomplish what I'm trying to do using only the Powershell script I have provided.

Comment: Diego, I've read the docs on the Copy and Register commands.  We did not have to go through all this the last time just to update the key-value parameters.  I must be missing some other step.

Comment: Have you tried just the update? I don't remember if you can update just parameters, try like this: `Start-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade -ApplicationName fabric:/Cantanilla.Jef -ApplicationTypeVersion 2.0.20 -Monitored -FailureAction Rollback -ApplicationParameter @{key:value pairs}`

Comment: Diego, the upgrade worked!  I could swear I tried that, and I got an error about the version already exists, but doing it using your syntax worked!  Do you want to update your answer to reflect anything or do you think it is right as is?  If so, I will mark it as answer.

Comment: Update Done! Thanks